# Auto duplicate last row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to duplicate the last row in a HTML table when the user types in any input inside the last row.

My code only works the first time it is run.

Maybe the table above it is being interfering with it? I also replaced :

```
if ( $(this).parents("tr").is("tr:last")) {
```

With

```
if ($(this).closest("tr").is(":last-child")) {
```

but this just causes a new row to be made on any input.
Var "t" might be off. I shrunk the size of the table and eyeballed the digits.

---

Javascript & Jquery

```
function deleteRow(row) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("Items").deleteRow(i);
}
function duperow() {
    document.getElementById("LastRow").value = (Number($("tr:last td:first").text()) + 1);
    var x = document.getElementById('Items');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = (Number($("tr:last td:first").text()) + 1);
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;
    var inp = [];
    for (t = 1; t < 4; t += 1) { 
        inp[t] = new_row.cells[t].querySelectorAll("input,select")[0];
        inp[t].id += len;
        inp[t].value = "";
    }
    inp[3].value = "0.00";
    x.appendChild(new_row);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").keydown(function () {
        if ( $(this).parents("tr").is("tr:last")) {
            duperow();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="test" action="submit.php" method="post"  accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="40%" class="alpha" cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Supplier Name:</p><input name="suplname" type="text" id="suplname" name="suplname" size="10" maxlength="30" required/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Contact:</p><input name="contact" type="text" id="contact" name="contact" size="10" maxlength="40" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <p>Address:</p><input name="address" type="text" id="address" name="address" size="10" maxlength="30" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="display: none;" name="LastRow" type="hidden" id="LastRow" name="LastRow" size="4" maxlength="4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="beta" id="Items" border="1" width="50%" cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
<tr>
    <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
    <th>Acct#</th>
    <th>Qty.</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td style="display: none;">1</td>
     <td><select name="acct" id="acct" >
             <option value=" " > </option>
             <option value="1" >Thing</option>
             <option value="2" >Thing2</option>
         </select></td>
     <td><input name="qty" type="number" id="qty" size="2" min="1" maxlength="6" required/></td>
     <td><input name="price" type="number" id="price" min="0.00" step="0.01"  value="0.00" style="width: 150px;"required/ onchange="total()"></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="deleterowbtn" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" id="addrowbtn" value="Add Item" onclick="duperow()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're binding to the keydown event listener on document.ready, which means that dynamically created input elements don't have anything bound to their keydown event.

You could do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table.beta").on("keydown", "input", function (e) {
        if ( $(e.target).parents("tr").is("tr:last")) {
            duperow();
        }
    });
});
```